# Unable to align the table rows with header after appendchild

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm trying to append the rows and header to an HTML table element using `onclick` event of button defined in HTML document. Although it successfully adds the header and rows, it fails to align the first element of the row with the header, and the page renders the table in a format like this :

[image: Click here to view Table render image]
Below is the JavaScript method for updating/adding records to table by appending rows and a header:

```js
 function updateTable(){
    var usr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    var i = testObject.length-1;
    var header = document.createElement("th");
    var usernode = document.createElement("td");
    var usertext = document.createTextNode("Username");
    usernode.appendChild(usertext);
    header.appendChild(usernode);
    var enode = document.createElement("td");
    var etext = document.createTextNode("Email");
    enode.appendChild(etext);
    header.appendChild(enode);
    var pnode = document.createElement("td");
    var ptext = document.createTextNode("Password");
    pnode.appendChild(ptext);
    header.appendChild(pnode);
    var lnode = document.createElement("td");
    var ltext = document.createTextNode("Location");
    lnode.appendChild(ltext);
    header.appendChild(lnode);
    var onode = document.createElement("td");
    var otext = document.createTextNode("Organization");
    onode.appendChild(otext);
    header.appendChild(onode);

    var noder = document.createElement("tr");
    var nodeu = document.createElement("td");
    var textu = document.createTextNode(usr[i].uname);
    nodeu.appendChild(textu);
    noder.appendChild(nodeu);
    var nodee = document.createElement("td");
    var texte = document.createTextNode(usr[i].email);
    nodee.appendChild(texte);
    noder.appendChild(nodee);
    var nodep = document.createElement("td");
    var textp = document.createTextNode(usr[i].pass);
    nodep.appendChild(textp);
    noder.appendChild(nodep);
    var nodel = document.createElement("td");
    var textl = document.createTextNode(usr[i].loc);
    nodel.appendChild(textl);
    noder.appendChild(nodel);
    var nodeo = document.createElement("td");
    var texto = document.createTextNode(usr[i].org);
    nodeo.appendChild(texto);
    noder.appendChild(nodeo);
    if(document.getElementById("t").querySelector("th")==null){
      document.getElementById("t").appendChild(header);
    }
    document.getElementById("t").appendChild(noder);
    clear();
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form.css">
</head>
<body>  

    <script src="form.js"></script>
     <p id="test"></p>
    <div id="userdiv">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="uname">
    </div>
    <div id="maildiv">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email">
    </div>
    <div id="passdiv">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Password" id="pass">
    </div>
     <div id="locdiv">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Location" id="loc">
     </div>
      <div id="orgdiv">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Organization" id="org">
        </div>
      <div id="gen">
        <input type="radio"/> Male
        <input type="radio"/> Female
    </div>
    <button id="submit" onclick="save()">Submit</button>
    <table id="t" border="1">
    </table>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: share the code not just an image

Comment: Any fixes so far guys?....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong element for the header.

"TH" is the equivalent for "TD", it's a cell, it goes inside a "TR".

You are adding TDs inside a TH, you actually need to add THs inside a TR. So change your `createdElement('th')` with `createElement('tr')` and the `createElement('td')` with `createElement('th')`.

I'd also recommend you to use THEAD and TBODY tags inside your table.

Answer (score 0):

Getting one bug, showing first row rendered adjacent to the header row..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbBnC.png)

Revised code :

```
function updateTable(){
    var usr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    var i = testObject.length-1;

    var noder = document.createElement("tr");
    if(i==0){
      var usernode = document.createElement("th");
      var usertext = document.createTextNode("Username");
      usernode.appendChild(usertext);
      noder.appendChild(usernode);
      var enode = document.createElement("th");
      var etext = document.createTextNode("Email");
      enode.appendChild(etext);
      noder.appendChild(enode);
      var pnode = document.createElement("th");
      var ptext = document.createTextNode("Password");
      pnode.appendChild(ptext);
      noder.appendChild(pnode);
      var lnode = document.createElement("th");
      var ltext = document.createTextNode("Location");
      lnode.appendChild(ltext);
      noder.appendChild(lnode);
      var onode = document.createElement("th");
      var otext = document.createTextNode("Organization");
      onode.appendChild(otext);
      noder.appendChild(onode);
    }


    var nodeu = document.createElement("td");
    var textu = document.createTextNode(usr[i].uname);
    nodeu.appendChild(textu);
    noder.appendChild(nodeu);
    var nodee = document.createElement("td");
    var texte = document.createTextNode(usr[i].email);
    nodee.appendChild(texte);
    noder.appendChild(nodee);
    var nodep = document.createElement("td");
    var textp = document.createTextNode(usr[i].pass);
    nodep.appendChild(textp);
    noder.appendChild(nodep);
    var nodel = document.createElement("td");
    var textl = document.createTextNode(usr[i].loc);
    nodel.appendChild(textl);
    noder.appendChild(nodel);
    var nodeo = document.createElement("td");
    var texto = document.createTextNode(usr[i].org);
    nodeo.appendChild(texto);
    noder.appendChild(nodeo);

    /*if(document.getElementById("t").querySelector("th")==null){
      document.getElementById("t").appendChild(header);
    }*/
    document.getElementById("t").appendChild(noder);

    clear();
  }
```

Comment: you are appending all TDs and THs to the same TR, use a new TR for the TDs